# Fixed effect in linear mixed model becomes non-significant when model is reduced

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis

I set up a linear mixed effects model with lme4 to test an interaction of two fixed effects condition1 and condition2 both with 2 levels and both manipulated within persons and items. In the study, each person gives a binary response to several items and I included by-person and by-item crossed random effects. The maximal model looks like this:

```
response ~ condition1 * condition2 + (condition1 * condition2 | subject) + (condition1 * condition2 | item)

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  4513.3   4664.5  -2232.6   4465.3     4008 

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-5.21298 -0.62610 -0.11388  0.64186  3.79176 

Random effects:
 Groups  Name                    Variance Std.Dev. Corr                
 subject (Intercept)             1.152110 1.07336                      
         condition1              1.235572 1.11156  -0.179              
         condition2              0.434862 0.65944   0.388 -0.222       
         cond1:cond2             0.253996 0.50398  -0.186  0.761 -0.019
 item    (Intercept)             0.161400 0.40175                      
         condition1              0.059284 0.24348  -0.104              
         condition2              0.071590 0.26756  -0.093  0.655       
         cond1:cond2             0.060364 0.24569  -0.216  0.980  0.766
Number of obs: 4032, groups:  subject, 84; item, 12

Fixed effects:
                         Estimate Std. Error z value  Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)             -0.083354   0.171607 -0.4857   0.62716    
condition1               0.743729   0.148089  5.0222 5.109e-07 ***
condition2               0.266932   0.115599  2.3091   0.02094 *  
condition1:condition2    0.255500   0.101319  2.5217   0.01168 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr)  cond1  cond2 
condition1  -0.141              
cond2        0.156  0.092       
con1:cond2  -0.173  0.708  0.340
optimizer (Nelder_Mead) convergence code: 0 (OK)
boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
```

The maximal model does not converge (singular fit). So, I reduced the model by removing the random effects correlations. The most complex model that converges successfully is the model excluding correlations for all random effects:

```
response ~ condition1 * condition2 + (condition1 * condition2 || subject) + (condition1 * condition2 || item)

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  4531.9   4607.5  -2253.9   4507.9     4020 

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-3.94852 -0.63341 -0.16449  0.64527  3.67447 

Random effects:
 Groups    Name                    Variance Std.Dev.
 subject   (Intercept)             1.061293 1.03019 
 subject.1 condition1              1.129036 1.06256 
 subject.2 condition2              0.358234 0.59853 
 subject.3 cond1:cond2             0.188754 0.43446 
 item      (Intercept)             0.159707 0.39963 
 item.1    condition1              0.037988 0.19491 
 item.2    condition2              0.073963 0.27196 
 item.3    cond1:cond2             0.030346 0.17420 
Number of obs: 4032, groups:  subject, 84; item, 12

Fixed effects:
                         Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)             -0.084391   0.166856 -0.5058 0.613015    
condition1               0.713344   0.136658  5.2199 1.79e-07 ***
condition2               0.311508   0.110707  2.8138 0.004896 ** 
cond1:cond2              0.151019   0.081093  1.8623 0.062563 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr)  cond1  cond2
condition1  -0.004              
condition2   0.007  0.008       
cond1:cond2  0.005  0.017 -0.001
```

My hypothesis concerns the fixed interaction effect. It is significant (p < .05) in the maximal, non-converging model, but not significant in the reduced model. Given that missing to model relevant random variation can inflate the alpha error rate [(Barr et al., 2013)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0749596X12001180?casa_token=qw8rNYPIF6oAAAAA:7h_-1C2ogz7tZspa0p1tDtYj_kI-SJcqZjmi_AwRCnoThsHmPBxhuOSNSLAtDVSfgLmG4ZdG) and that a maximal model can lead to loss of statistical power [(Matuscheck et al., 2017)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0749596X17300013), I would have expected the reversed pattern of results: a non-significant effect in the maximal model and a significant, potentially false-positive, effect in the reduced model. I understood that a maximal/overfitted model is typicalle the more conservative choice and though suboptimal on power it can safeguard against the often-worse false positive error. But this does not seem to be the case here. How can this be explained?

---

Here are some more details on the discussion on how the random effects structure affects alpha error rate and power:

Barr et al. (2013) conclude from their simulation studies that a "failure to include the maximal random-effect structures (when such random effects are present in the underlying population)" increases alpha error rates, especially if random effects for the fixed effects of interest are not accounted for. At the same time a data-driven reduction of the model led to only very small improvements in power. Therefore, they recommend to fit the maximal random effect structure, if possible. Moreover, their simulations suggest that a model excluding the random effects correlations performed similarly well as the maximal model.

Matuscheck et al. (2017) show in simulation studies that a maximal model tends to be overly conservative when random slope variance is small while a more parsimonious, reduced model (excluding random slopes for the fixed effect of interest and random effects correlations) had higher power and an alpha error rate close to the nominal alpha level in this case. This seemed to be even more the case when sample/cluster size was small (i.e., detecting random effects becomes more difficult). As random effects variance increases, the alpha error rate increases for the maximal and the reduced model (a bit faster for the reduced model) while power decreases with increasing random slopes variance but a bit more slowly for the reduced model.

I concluded from this that a reduced model is generally more liberal (but not necessarily too liberal, especially if only random effects correlations are removed) and tends to have more statistical power than the maximal model. But this conclusion may be
overly simple.

Comment: I did some simple simulations and found that the p-values for the fixed effects in singular models with a single random slope tend to be smaller than those in non-singular zero-correlation models. The standard errors were larger, but the the degrees of freedom were larger still, resulting in smaller p-values. Since p-values from mixed models are only approximations anyway, I don't find this to be surprising or worrying.

Comment: @RobertLong Thanks a lot, this is really interesting! So here it seems that the more complex model has higher statistical power (if in your simulation there was a real effect?). Would you say that the "better" model is still the reduced model in this case (better fit, more conservative)?

Comment: You're welcome. You could say that, but I I wouldn't. The diffferences in the p-values are too small and highly dependent on the degrees of freedom approximation.  I don't know what justification Barr gives for expecting lower power ? Can you elaborate ? I would expect it to be highly dependent on various things such as number of clusters, clustrer size, variances of the random effects, correlations between the random effects. size of fixed effectss etc. It's a very interesting problem and would benefit from a simulation study to investigate. I can share my simulation code if interested ?

Comment: @RobertLong I added some more details on the discussion of power/alpha error rate to the post. Hope this is informative. If I haven’t overlooked this, neither Barr et al. nor Matuscheck et al. test how different amounts of correlations between random effects affect the fixed effects results. Maybe this is the culprit here. I agree that a simulation study may help. I would be grateful for your code and will give it a try. Thank you.